# Wordpress custom loop failing after installing a filter plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've been using this loop for a while now and it's worked perfectly. Until I recently added a plugin and customized that to filter results of the same custom post type on a different page. For some reason, this loop stopped working, so I removed the plugin but that didn't fix it either. I've tried rewriting the code and no luck. Can anyone help me with ideas as to how to fix this?

````
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
                            'post_type' => 'namskeid',
                            'meta_type' => DATE,
                            'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'meta_key'  => 'course_date',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array (
                                'key' => 'course_type_display',
                                'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                                'value' => get_the_ID( 180 )
                            ))
                        );


$namskeid = new WP_Query($args);

if($namskeid->have_posts()) : while($namskeid->have_posts()) : $namskeid->the_post() ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h5><?php the_title();?></h5></a><?php 
         $courseDate = new DateTime(get_field('course_date')); ?>
        <p><strong>Dagsetning: </strong> <?php echo $courseDate->format('d. m. Y'); ?><br>
        <?php the_field('course_excerpt')?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">Meira</a>
        <a href="<?php the_field('course_registration')?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Skráning</a>
        

       
        <hr>
<?php 
              
    endwhile;

else :  echo "Engin námskeið skráð í " . get_the_title() .  " á næstunni. Hafið samband við Ökuland fyrir frekari upplýsingar.";

endif;
//If more námskeið than 2 then show button, else only display námskeið.

if(count($namskeid) >= 2) {
        
} else {
    echo "<a href='". home_url('namskeid') . "'class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary'>Fleiri námskeið</a>";
}

wp_reset_query(  ); ?>```

Thanks!
````

Comment: What does your debug say? Do you get an error?

Comment: You're missing quotes around 'DATE' and there's no value for it.